# Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) Jhipster with EHCache on Heroku

Tags: heroku, jhipster, ehcache

I have a jhipster generated app on heroku and since the first deploy, without doing any modifications, I have the classic Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded). After several investigations I still can not fix this issue. Now I have 300 user, the usage of the application is very basic, but still I want to get rid of this errror.  What I have done so far:

1- set -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap on the JAVA-TOOLS options of heroku

2- I wanted to also set the -Xmx300m , but given the fact that heroku already applies -Xmx256m, I think is no needed to reset this value.

The last comments that I have read, points me to remove the usage of the cache, something that I think will decrease the performance of the app cause all the sql queries will go to the database. I am using EHCache as a local cache, have any of you guys fixed this situation by removing or reconfiguring EHCAche? or is there any recommendation to fix this situation?

My application has never crashed, but I fear that the performance will degrade overtime.

Comment: I wouldn’t worry about it. I’ve had JHipster apps on Heroku for a few years with this issue. It doesn’t seem to effect anything.

Comment: Thanks @MattRaible, but don't you think that the VM could be swaping? I mean, that is what heroku says that happens when an application has this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using these JAVA_OPTS:

```
-Xmx256m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=50m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=80m -XX:ParallelGCThreads=3 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

And these Spring opts:

```
--server.undertow.io-threads=1
```

This is similar to the ideal configuration we found for the [jhipster-registry](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry). The idea is to reduce the number of threads (and thus the memory for thread stacks) and reduce other off-heap memory.

Comment: I didn't used all of those features cause I wanted to understand them before, so I used JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx256m -Xss512k -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=80m And the application did not start, it has OutOfMemoryError, I suppose that the metaspace was too small.

Comment: Try increasing metaspace until it works. It depends mostly on class count so should be consistent

Comment: I am not facing this issue anymore, but I dont know if this was a change on the Heroku side, or some improvements I have made in the app, nevertheless, I set the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS to -Xmx256m -Xss512k -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=100m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=50m